# Is this really saving allocation?

Tags: c#

I've got the following in a static Utility class:

```
static int[] MonthDays = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31};
public static int[] GetListOfAllDaysForMonths()
{
    return MonthDays;
}
```

Is this efficient in that now by calling GetListOfAllDaysForMonths() in several places in code, that I am saving myself from having to allocate and create a new int[] each time this method is called?

Updated: Lets make it readonly

```
 static readonly int[]
```

Comment: I'm really curious *how* this is used...

Comment: I'm wondering why this level of premature-optimization is so common high-level "managed" languages.

Comment: it's used as a default list of numbers in a Day dropdown for in a Month/day/year scenario so we don't have to manually type this in a bunch of code-behind classes

Comment: @coffeeaddict: `readonly` doesn't do what you want; it makes the *array* readonly, not the elements.

Comment: @coffeeaddict:  If that's the case, I would make a control, hard-code the days dropdown and use the control in all your forms.

Comment: yea, I know I just don't have time to make that control right now.

Comment: I would make the entries in your arrays strings rather than ints - a dropdown list uses strings, and so each int would have to be coverted with ToString() every time it is used.

Comment: @pst: Funny how that works, isn't it. I'd be willing to bet that almost any implementation of this routine will be so fast, and use so little memory, as to not make any difference. The obvious exception being reading the list of days from a database, which I'm sure somebody has tried before...

Answer (score 10):

Yes, but you also open for some interesting side effects. Consider this:

```
int[] a = GetListOfAllDaysForMonths();
a[3] = 200;
int[] b = GetListOfAllDaysForMonths();
Console.WriteLine(b[3]);  // prints 200
```

**Update**
Given the intended use (default numbers for day-of-month in dropdown lists), you will need many (and I mean *many*, as in hundreds of thousands or millions) such lists for this kind of optimization to make a difference. I would not spend time trying to optimize this from memory allocation perspective; it simply will not be worth it.

For now, I would recommend you to just have a method return a new `int[]` (exposed as an `IEnumerable<int>`) with the numbers for each call. Then, at a later date, if you happen to identify this to pose a problem with memory or performance, then you can optimize that method.

Comment: I've updated my post.  I actually will make this a readonly int[] array.

Comment: we don't do the "after" on performance.  Unnecessary allocations are obvious reductions to aim for and automatically help the cause of performance improvement in an overall application.

Comment: @coffee: "after" is the only correct way to test performance.  Otherwise, you're just guess and will likely miss the more important bottleneck in favor of micro-optimizations.

Comment: Joel, of course you need to test after.  But there are obvious things that you don't need to wait for.  One of them is reducing unnecessary allocations which is a given.  Creating an object when it should only be and needs to only be created once is a huge efficiency gain.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is effectively allowing you to re-use the same array and not re-allocate a new one each time.

However, since you are returning an array (which is mutable) you cannot guarantee that the caller of your method isn't modifying the array once you return it.  It would be much better to return an `IEnumerable<T>` or a [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) so that you can be sure that no one is modifying the collection besides you.  (This has nothing to do with performance - just something I thought would be important to point out.)

Comment: well this is a readonly array...it's only going to be used to populate a dropdown for days in a month...the default number of days.

Comment: @coffee: it's _not_ readonly.  You just happen to only ever read from it.  There's an important difference there.

Comment: I'll be adding the keyword readonly to the int[].  See my updated thread.

Answer (score 6):

If this is truely to populate a dropdown, why not use DateTime's [`DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) static method to get the number of days given the year and month, then create an array containing those values (using Enumerable.Range or some such) to populate the dropdown?

```
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2009, 10); // returns 31
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2009, 2); // returns 28
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2012, 2); // returns 29
DateTime.DaysInMonth(2009, 9); // returns 30
```

Comment: because look at all the hard coded numbers there and this method is to be reused in multiple asp.net pages.

Comment: your code is very long.  All I'd have to do ist just bind to the returned static int[] to my dropdown, one line of code!

Comment: myDropdown.DataSource = GetListOfAllDaysForMonths();  This only happens on first load of the page to give the dropdown a default set of numbers for days.  The selected value will be something like "-Day=".  We will start with 31 numbers as a good starting point.  When the user changes the month, this day dropdown will change dynamically with javascript.

Comment: I only hard-coded them as examples. I assumed you'd be feeding those values in from another source, then use something like pmarflee's answer to turn it into an array

Comment: there's no need to feed those values in from another source.  There are 31 days by default in a month.  We are not setting it to a particular month however we do need something in the day dropdownlist for JavaScript to run with.

Comment: There aren't 29 days in Feb-2010... There will be in 2012.

Comment: "By default" has no meaning when applied to days in a month.  7 months out of every year have 31 days.  What about the other 5?  What about February?  Leap years  As R. Bemrose points out, the framework already performs this logic for you.  Use it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will only be created once, although be aware that if any code decides to modify the return value then it will be reflected for all other callers, so it may be preferable to return a new copy each time. Alternatively you could only expose `IEnumerable<int>` instead. Incidently, you could also replace the initialiser to:

`static int[] MonthDays = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).ToArray()`

Comment: +1 for showing a better way to do it. Hand-typing stuff like this is prone to tyepos. Way, way, way better to do it procedurally.

Comment: Also typing it out makes him data entry not programmer.

Comment: I hate hand typing this crap.. I agree.

Comment: but how is it created once, is it the first time any of the code in your application uses the static class that contains this?  When is that int[] created, what action in reference to the static class being used?

Comment: I'd remove the .ToArray and just keep it as an IEnumerable.  That's likely the best way to handle this: _**never**_ have the entire array in memory.

Comment: it has to be in memory somehow, so how would leaving that out be any different?

Comment: It does _all_ have to be in memory: but it doesn't all have to be in memory _at the same time_.  You can _stream_ it.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn (1st response): That depends on the way it's accessed. If it needs to be accessed by index for whatever reason, `ToArray` or `ToList` would be the way to store it. If it's always accessed as part of a foreach loop, then yes, I agree, IEnumerable. Or don't even store it in memory at all, just use `foreach(var num in Enumerable.Range(1, 31))`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also initialize the variable with [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx).

```
static int[] MonthDays = Enumerable.Range(1, 31).ToArray();
```

Comment: I'd remove the .ToArray and just keep it as an IEnumerable. That's likely the best way to handle this: **_never_** have the entire array in memory.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that you will save allocating a new array every time GetListOfAllDaysForMonths is called by using the static variable.  What's ambiguous is whether or not this is a worthwhile change for your code.  That answer is highly dependent on the use cases of this method within your application.  Only a profiler can tell you if this is a worthwhile savings.

Comment: everything we do for our e-commerce site is worth while to save allocations.

Comment: I don't think it takes a profiler in this situation.  The less instances you are allocating in any application the better your performance.  You always aim for lowest object count and save allocations where possible.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it makes a difference, it is so small as to make it completely irrelevant. Micro optimizations are pointless (except for the few times they aren't, the only way you will know what those are is if you run into bottlenecks). Don't let the allocation of a 12 element array bother you, instead focus on algorithmic efficacy, because that is where you will see a difference.

Answer (score 1):

why optimise this? it's premature, the value you get out of doing this is probably so small you'll never notice it. If it ever did become a problem, then that is the time you optimise, doing so before hand is a waste of time, resource and can make code unnecessarily complicated and messy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the built-in ASP.NET [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684139(VS.85).aspx) control rather than rolling your own date picker?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind that callers can change the array and mess up other callers, then this an optimization, but tricky in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If this is used just to populate drop downs, then how about a method like this:

```
populateDaysList(ListItemsCollection items) {
  items.Add(new ListItem("1"));
  items.Add(new ListItem("2"));
  items.Add(new ListItem("3"));
  ...
  items.Add(new ListItem("31"));
}
```

No need for an array or an iterator (for or foreach) to read through it

Comment: Ugh, no.  If you're going to do this, you may as well hard-code the html for the drop down list.  _That_ would be the fastest thing.

Comment: fastest maybe, but a lot of repeated code. The ideal thing would be a custom control with this code built-in. Since the questioner said he was not going to do that, I believe this to be a good way avoid the code repetition with good performance (even if it is a lttle ugly).

Comment: because you're again hard coding a LOT there.  I like the Enumerator where you aren't hard coding a bunch of numbers.  Those are magic strings that are unecessary.  You can just bind to the array, one line.

Comment: Your question asked about efficiency, not elegance. I agree that the Enumberable trick is elegant. However, for performance, my way eliminates data binding, for/foreach loops, and int-to-string conversions (31 of them every time you load a drop-down list). Hard coded, yes, but only once, and pretty easy to get right.

Comment: @coffeeaddict - good point about hard-coding. You never know when they'll add a new month with 32 days!